# Open source 'Motion Chart' or 'Trendalyzer'?

Tags: google-visualization

If you don't want to, or can't use the Google Visualization service, are there (preferably open source) substitutes to use to have motion charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vizabi is open source, from GapMinder.

https://github.com/Gapminder/vizabi

See examples here:

http://static.gapminderdev.org/vizabi/develop/preview/

Answer (score 2):

Open source Java chart built on top of JFreeChart developed by peeps at [UCLA SOCR](http://www.socr.ucla.edu/SOCR_MotionCharts/). Not as elegant as Google's MotionChart but [open source on google code](http://code.google.com/p/socr/source/browse/). It feels really slow but not sure if that's because of demo is running as an applet.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on your needs. 
Motion chart is almost the only visualization tool with rich features suitable for multidimensional display over timeline.

Comment: So, how does it *depend* on my needs? Any (even inferior) alternatives you know? Please share if you do.